# Bootstrap panel height 100% over size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the below code, I am trying to find why the panel is expanding over its parent height from bottom.

```
<!--Beginning of Chart 1 -->
<div id="chartBox1" class="max col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
    <!-- Beginning of Panel For Chart 1 -->
        <div class="panel panel-default max">
          <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
          <div class="panel-body max">

          </div>
        </div>
    <!--/ End of Panel For Chart 1 -->
</div>
<!--/ End of Chart 1 -->
```

CSS style is:

```
body, html{height:100%;}
.row{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
.max{height:100%;}
#rightBox{background-color:#E3E3E3;}
#topCharts{height:50%;}
#botCharts{height:50%;}
#chartBox1{background-color:red; padding:10px;}
#chartBox2{background-color:green; padding:10px;}
#chartBox3{background-color:blue; padding:10px;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that the parent's height is `500px`. Since the `.panel-body` is set to have a height of `100%` of the parent, its height will also be `500px`. Add this to the height of the `.panel-heading` and the panel will always extend outside of the parent because the height of the heading isn't taken into consideration.

There are a couple of solutions:

- Use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to displace the height of the heading.

  In this case, the height of the `.panel-heading` elements is ~`40px`.

  ```
  .panel-body {
      height: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
  ```
- Absolutely position the heading element at the top of the parent and use padding to displace it.

  ```
  .panel {
      position:relative;
  }
  .panel > .panel-heading {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
  }
  .panel > .panel-body {
      padding-top:40px;
  }
  ```